# Problem with PDF output, huge stickybox/comment

Tags: pdf, paper-size

There seems to be a problem with the PDF generated by PDFLatex.
I need very small magnification levels(7.5%) to read the file properly.
Moreover, if I want to comment something, the commentbox is HUGE and I have to spend a long time to resize it.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? 
Thank you very much !

EDIT: An old file that previously did not have the problem now has the same problem. I guess it has to do something with adobe then..

EDIT2: It was a problem with the Adobe Reader DC. Re-Installation solved it, I guess there was something wrong with the settings. Thread can be closed

Kind Regards,
RM

Comment: you,as the author,  can delete the question